# maven - how to make a project with executable jar file

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have a maven app and I want to make an executable `.jar` from it. I tried using `maven-jar-plugin`, but when I run the `.jar` file made from maven-jar-plugin, it gives an error: `Can't find main manifest`. I also tried using `maven-assembly-plugin`, but it gives an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [appContext.xml]

I tried using `maven-shade-plugin`, but it gives the same error with the `NamespaceHandler`. I looked everywhere and I can't seem to find the solution to the problem.

My app also uses a `.jar` from a different app, that is added to the classpath. I also tried putting them in the same directory, but that doesn't work either.

Parts of my `pom.xml` file:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
           .
           .
           .
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>

                <configuration>
                        <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>

                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.escomled.machinelearning.ml.Escomled_Streams_H2O_ML</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My `appContext.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd ">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.escomled" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.escomled.*" />
    <import resource="classpath*:config/blackBoard.xml" />
    <task:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///home/escomled/escomled_server/config/escomled.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="blackboard" class="com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl">
        <property name="hazelcastInstance" ref="hazelcastClient" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I tried a lot of things and none of them worked, the `.jar` is not working, so can someone tell me from the beginning how to do it and what am I doing wrong?
(I will edit my question if you need additional info, just comment)

Answer (score 0):

While using maven-assembly-plugin did you try running this command:

`mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package`

Comment: It gives me this error: `Could not find goal 'assembly' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0 among available goals`. I ran it with `mvn assembly:single -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package`, but when I ran the `-jar-with-dependencies package` with java -jar *jar-name*.jar it gave me the same error with the NamespaceHandler.